# Copy Event from One Calendar to another

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am creating an app in asp.net for Google calendar integration. When we insert a particular event to the calendar then at the same point i want to copy the same calendar event in to another calendar and i want to do the same process in a single request. So may any one please guide me for this problem. I am using google calendar version 3 for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that they be two separate Calendar events? If not, you should be adding the second calendar as an attendee of the event rather than creating a copy of the event. See the [events reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) and look for the attendees list attribute. This can be achieved in a single API call.

If it is indeed necessary that the events are entirely separate and independent of each other, it will require two [events.insert()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) operations, one on each calendar. However, as long as the user you are authenticating as has access to both calendars, it should be possible to [batch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch) the two operations into a single HTTP call.

Comment: thanks for your reply but my problem is that, I am having two calendars one is private and another one is shared, if i am going to insert an event in my private calendar then it should generate a separate copy to my shared calendar also, so that other can see to my shared calendar. i can do this process in a single process and i am having the calendar ID of both calendar.